# XAMPP 3.2.1 Virtualhost is not working

Tags: php, apache, dns, xampp, virtualhost

I am using XAMPP 3.2.1 and creating new virtual host in `http-vhosts.conf` file in Apache the code below

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/support/srinet"
  ServerName supportcenter.sevplcorp.com
  Alias /mrpdf "E:/temp"
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/support/srinet">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I open `supportcenter.sevplcorp.com` in browser windows it shows like below

[image]

Comment: did you have defined this host in your `hosts` file as well? you must restart your web server when you made any changes in `.conf` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit your host file located at : %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.
Add a newline 127.0.0.1    supportcenter.sevplcorp.com

Comment: @JeysinghAnbu, at port 8080 (`supportcenter.sevplcorp.com:8080`) as well?

Comment: @mitkosoft `supportcenter.sevplcorp.com:8080` is working . Thanks. I tried `supportcenter.sevplcorp.com`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you haven't altered your hosts file to map the host domain to server's IP address. Assuming that you're running XAMPP on your own PC, open your editor as Administrator (notepad is sufficient), then open this file:

`c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

...and add this line to the bottom:

`127.0.0.1    supportcenter.sevplcorp.com`

Save the file and, after that, visiting supportcenter.sevplcorp.com should work. Basically, by altering the hosts file you're telling the browser (and everything else that might want to access supportcenter.sevplcorp.com) that it's actually your PC.

Comment: @JeysinghAnbu put whatever file in your document root, e.g. "test.txt" and then try to visit it at http://supportcenter.sevplcorp.com:8080/test.txt ...and make sure your Apache has been restarted after configuring the vhost.